# it seems that the alias "as" no longer works in the build angular

Tags: angular, typescript

update my angular application 7.0.0 to 7.2.9. but when making the production build it says "ERROR ReferenceError: _environment_1 is not defined"

I'm using the environment as well:

import { environment as ENV } from 'environments/environment.ts';

the alias(as ENV) is no longer working.

in version 7.0.0 this did not happen

my package.json

```
{
"name": "example",
"version": "0.0.0",
"scripts": {
"ng": "ng",
"start": "ng serve",
"build:prod": "ng build --configuration=prod",
"build:dev": "ng build --configuration=dev",
"test": "ng test",
"lint": "ng lint",
"e2e": "ng e2e"
},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "~7.2.9",
"@angular/common": "~7.2.9",
"@angular/compiler": "~7.2.9",
"@angular/core": "~7.2.9",
"@angular/forms": "~7.2.9",
"@angular/http": "~7.2.9",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.9",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.9",
"@angular/router": "~7.2.9",
"@ngrx/effects": "^7.3.0",
"@ngrx/store": "^7.3.0",
"@ngrx/store-devtools": "^7.3.0",
"@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
"@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
"core-js": "^2.5.4",
"js-sha512": "^0.8.0",
"rxjs": "~6.4.0",
"tiny-slider": "2.9.1",
"zone.js": "~0.8.26"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.10.0",
"@angular/cli": "~7.3.6",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.9",
"@angular/language-service": "~7.2.9",
"@types/faker": "^4.1.4",
"@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
"@types/node": "~8.9.4",
"codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
"faker": "^4.1.0",
"http-server": "^0.11.1",
"husky": "^1.2.1",
"jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
"json-server": "0.14.0",
"karma": "~3.0.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
"karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
"protractor": "~5.4.0",
"ts-node": "~7.0.0",
"tslint": "~5.11.0",
"typescript": "~3.2.4",
"webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.0.3"
}
}
```

Comment: You sure that it works without `as ENV`?

Comment: @PrzemyslawPietrzak Yes, but I want to handle the alias but in the update of angular and it does not work it says "ERROR ReferenceError: _environment_1 is not defined"

Comment: code works for me - without the .ts on the end `import { environment as ENV } from 'environments/environment';`